# Properties allowed in Liquibase - Constraints

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to add a new table in the DB using Liquibase.

I am putting Constraints inside the table definition and have a foreign key in it. Without having an extra `addForeignKey` code snippet.

So I am trying to use this. But it says `onDelete` is not allowed in `constraints` . Its also a little hard to find any documentation related to this. Other properties do get allowed though.

```
  <createTable tableName="relationship_view_person">
     <column name="view_id" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_view_person_reln" referencedTableName="configured_view" referencedColumnNames="view_id" onDelete="CASCADE" />
     </column>
     <column name="person_id" type="TEXT">
        <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_person_view_reln" referencedTableName="persons" referencedColumnNames="person_id" onDelete="CASCADE" />
     </column>
  </createTable>
```

I get this error

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'onDelete' is not allowed to appear in element 'constraints'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout [this documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-column.html) for `add column` in liquibase. And scroll till you are on `Constraints tag` section. You will find all the attributes allowed with liquibase `constraints` tag.

As per the error you are getting for `onDelete` is not allowed, please try using attribute `deleteCascade="true"` like below:

```
<createTable tableName="relationship_view_person">
     <column name="view_id" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_view_person_reln" referencedTableName="configured_view" referencedColumnNames="view_id" deleteCascade="true" />
     </column>
     <column name="person_id" type="TEXT">
        <constraints nullable="false" foreignKeyName="fk_person_view_reln" referencedTableName="persons" referencedColumnNames="person_id" deleteCascade="true" />
     </column>
  </createTable>
```

On running `updateSQL` it will generate the expected SQL query for you (which you can verify before executing it directly on DB):

```
CREATE TABLE public.relationship_view_person (view_id BIGINT NOT NULL, person_id TEXT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_view_person_reln FOREIGN KEY (view_id) REFERENCES public.configured_view(view_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT fk_person_view_reln FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES public.persons(person_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Note: `onDelete` attribute works with `addForeignKeyConstraint` tag in liquibase. Find documentation for it [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-foreign-key-constraint.html).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

You said

> **I am putting Constraints inside the table definition and have a foreign key in it. Without having an extra addForeignKey code snippet.**

As exception suggest you are not allow to set unknown element line `onDelete` with in `<constraint>` tag, furthermore the set of possible configuration with in `<constraint>` till the latest [version](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases) (`4.*.*`) are as follow.

```html
    <!-- Attributes for constraints -->
    <xsd:attributeGroup name="constraintsAttributes">
        <xsd:attribute name="nullable" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="primaryKey" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="primaryKeyName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="primaryKeyTablespace" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="unique" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="uniqueConstraintName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="references" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="referencedTableName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="referencedColumnNames" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="foreignKeyName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="deleteCascade" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="deferrable" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="initiallyDeferred" type="booleanExp"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="checkConstraint" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
```